# Optimizing the following hackerrank program

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

I want to optimize the following code I made so that it passes all the test cases in a hackerrank problem. It works at the moment but fails some cases due to timeout. Can you guide me as to how to optimize the code without changing the concept?

**QUESTION**

> Alice is playing an arcade game and wants to climb to the top of the leaderboard. 
>   Can you help her track her ranking as she beats each level? The game uses Dense Ranking, so its leaderboard works like this:
>
> • The player with the highest score is ranked number on the leaderboard.
>
> • Players who have equal scores receive the same ranking number, and the next player(s) receive the immediately following ranking number.
>
> For example, four players have the scores 100, 90, 90, and 80. Those players will have ranks 1, 2, 2 and 3 respectively.
>
> When Alice starts playing, there are already `n` people on the leaderboard. Alice plays for `m` levels, and we denote her total score after passing each level.After completing each level, Alice wants to know her current rank.
>
> You are given an array of monotonically decreasing leaderboard scores, and another array of Alice's cumulative scores for each level of the game. You must print  integers: the integer should indicate the current rank of Alice after passing each level.
>
> **Input Format:**
>
> - The first line contains an integer `n`, denoting the number of players already on the leaderboard.
> - The next line contains `n` space-separated integers describing the respective values of their scores.
> - The next line contains an integer `m`, denoting the number of levels Alice beats.
> - The last line contains `m` space-separated integers describing the respective values of each player.
>
> **Output Format:**
>
> Print  integers. The  integer should indicate the rank of Alice after passing each  level.

**INPUT**

```
7
100 100 50 40 40 20 10
4
5 25 50 120
```

**OUTPUT**

```
6
4
2
1
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct player {
    int rank;
    int score;
};

struct node {
    struct player data;
    struct node *next;
};

int main() {
    int n, i, m, temp, count = 1, x;
    struct node *ptr, *head;
    head = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    ptr = head;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &x);
        ptr->data.score = x;
        if (x < temp)
            count++;
        ptr->data.rank = count;
        temp = ptr->data.score;
        ptr->next = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    ptr = NULL;
    ptr = head;
    scanf("%d", &m);
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        scanf(" %d", &x);
        while (x < ptr->data.score)
            ptr = ptr->next;
        if (ptr->next == NULL)
            ptr->data.rank = count + 1;
        printf("%d\n", ptr->data.rank);
        ptr = head;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The problem lies in the fact that I am traversing the linked list from the beginning each time I am taking out the rank for Alice. What might be a possible optimization for this?

Comment: The point of such questions is not necessarily just to write efficient code, but to find a smart algorithm. **That** is the real challenge you must solve.

Comment: I know. I tried and I could not come to an efficient program using linked lists to my problem. So if you could just help me out a bit, that would be great. :)
It's possible to do the problem by using stacks but I want to use only linked lists.

Comment: Brutally - if you can't solve it, try another challenge. This site isn't a solve-my-challenge site, but for specific problems with C.

Comment: I will keep on trying other challenges but that's not really the point of me posting in stackoverflow, is it?

Comment: My answer to that, is if I could solve the problem I would submit it directly to Hackerrank, not give it to you. If I can't solve it, I would put the problem aside and come back to it later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reverse the list representing the leaderboard, such that the leaderboard is monotonically increasing. If the leaderboard is ordered that way, you only need to traverse the leaderboard starting from the last position. I.e. for your example-input:

```
10/5    20/4    40/3    40/3     50/2     100/1     100/1           leaderboard
5               25               50                           120   score
6               4                2                            1     pos
```

As pseudocode:

```
node n = leaderboard.reverse().head

foreach score in scorelist:
    while n != null and n.score > score
        n = n.next

    if n == null:
        print 1
    else:
        print n.pos - 1
```

This works because based on the position of `score[i]` in the leaderboard (`l[j]`), we know that `score[i + 1]` must be in position `l[j + x]`, where `x > 0` in the reversed leaderboard.

Comment: Got it. Thank you. The efficiency is greatly affected by this I see.

Comment: @Adirtha glad I could help :).
Don't forget to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer, if it solved your problem ;). Welcome to SO

Answer (score 0):

There is undefined behavior in your code as you do not initialize the `temp` variable:  The first comparison `if (x < temp)` has undefined behavior, so `count` may be incremented incorrectly.

Paul's approach is a very good solution to decrease the complexity from **O(N<sup>2</sup>)** to **O(N)**.

Here is the modified code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int rank;
    int score;
    struct node *next;
};

int main(void) {
    int n, i, m, last = 0, rank = 1, x;
    struct node *ptr, *head = NULL;
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1)
        return 1;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr));
        if (ptr == NULL)
            return 1;
        if (scanf("%d", &ptr->score) != 1)
            return 1;
        if (ptr->score < last)
            rank++;
        ptr->rank = rank;
        last = ptr->score;
        ptr->next = head;
        head = ptr;
    }
    if (scanf("%d", &m) != 1)
        return 1;
    for (ptr = head, i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        if (scanf(" %d", &x) != 1)
            return 1;
        while (ptr && x > ptr->score)
            ptr = ptr->next;
        if (ptr == NULL)
            rank = 1;
        else
        if (x == ptr->score)
            rank = ptr->rank;
        else
            rank = ptr->rank + 1;
        printf("%d\n", rank);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank You. Code is much better and efficient now.